# Prolog binary tree - Syntax error: Operator Expected

Tags: prolog, binary-tree, syntax-error

Im trying to write a binary tree in prolog but getting the following error:

```
Syntax error: Operator expected
```

The error occurs here in the first call to addChildren:

```
addChildren(node(Left, Right, Cand, [(Name, Profit, Weight)|T])):-
getTotalWeight(Cand, 0, Total),
%if total weight is less than 20
((Total + Weight) < 20 -> %then
    New = [Cand | (Name, Profit, Weight)],
    addChildren(Left(_,_, New, T)), %error here
    addChildren(Right(_,_, Cand, T))
; %else
    %end).
```

I'm using the following node:

```
node(node, node, [], []).
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Left(_,_, New, T)
```

is not a valid compound term, since the functor may not be a variable (uppercased identifier). Use

```
left(_, _, New, T)
```

instead, and similarly for `Right`.

Comment: And the function definition to `addChildren(node(left, right, Cand, [(Name, Profit, Weight)|T])):-` , too?